# How do you catch exceptions in Project Reactor?

Tags: java, project-reactor

`https://httpbin.org/status/404` returns a 404 error. Always. How do I catch it and why did my attempts to do so fail?

Here's the code. I actually wrapped the snippets in JUnit tests (like so: `@Test{/*snippet*/}`). I omitted it in the code below

You can see that there's something wrong with the request at all only if you `block()`

```java
WebClient.builder().build()
        .get()
        .uri("https://httpbin.org/status/404")
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(String.class)
        .block();
```

> org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$NotFound: 404 Not Found from GET https‌://httpbin.org/status/404

However, if I simply subscribe and try to catch it, nothing happens at all. Here's what I tried:

#### Attempt №1. Passing a `Throwable` `Consumer`

```java
WebClient.builder().build()
        .get()
        .uri("https://httpbin.org/status/404")
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(String.class)
        .subscribe(
                s -> System.out.println("Success: " + s),
                t -> System.out.println("Failure: " + t.getMessage()));
```

#### Attempt №2. Calling `onErrorReturn()` with a fallback

```java
WebClient.builder().build()
        .get()
        .uri("https://httpbin.org/status/404")
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(String.class)
        .onErrorReturn("Fallback")
        .subscribe(
                s -> System.out.println("Success: " + s),
                t -> System.out.println("Failure: " + t.getMessage()));
```

#### Attempt №3. Calling `onErrorResume()` and returning an empty `Mono` from the callback

```java
WebClient.builder().build()
        .get()
        .uri("https://httpbin.org/status/404")
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(String.class)
        .onErrorResume(t -> {
            log.warn("Could not access the resource: " + t.getMessage());
            return Mono.empty();
        })
        .subscribe(
                s -> System.out.println("Success: " + s),
                t -> System.out.println("Failure: " + t.getMessage())
        );
```

No exceptions, no logs of any kind (as if there's no success and no failure either).

I genuinely tried to read [this reference guide](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/), but I unfortunately didn't find it very helpful. It, in my opinion, has two extremes: too easy (`Flux.just(1,2,3)`) and too complex (or at least explained not too well)

Answer (score 0):

They execute the code in some daemon thread, so the JVM quits before my error handling kicks in. This works:

```java
WebClient.builder().build()
        .get()
        .uri("https://httpbin.org/status/404")
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(String.class)
        .subscribe(
                s -> System.out.println("Success: " + s),
                t -> System.out.println("Failure: " + t.getMessage())
        );
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

> Failure: 404 Not Found from GET https‌://httpbin.org/status/404

I wonder what was behind that design decision, and how I was supposed to know it. When I read this, it never occurred to me they would dedicate some daemon

> Obtaining a Flux or a Mono does not necessarily mean that it runs in a dedicated Thread. Instead, most operators continue working in the Thread on which the previous operator executed. Unless specified, the topmost operator (the source) itself runs on the Thread in which the subscribe() call was made.

I believed `subscribe()` was invoked in the main thread

Here's what I found in the guide, it's somewhat similar to my situation

> ```
> Flux<String> flux = Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(250))
>    .map(input -> {
>        if (input < 3) return "tick " + input;
>        throw new RuntimeException("boom");
>    })
>    .onErrorReturn("Uh oh");
>
> flux.subscribe(System.out::println);
> Thread.sleep(2100);
> ```
>
> Note that interval executes on a timer Scheduler by default. If we want to run that example in a main class, we would need to add a sleep call here so that the application does not exit immediately without any value being produced.

Comment: You should remove the question from your answer. If you want to ask a follow-up question, ask a new question (though make sure you ask for factual things, and not for opinion like _"how was I supposed to know it?"_, or why something was designed a certain way).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I hope I don't regret following your advice. Asking questions on SO is a risky business