# Are Project Reactor's error handlers run in some daemon by default?

Tags: java, project-reactor

*It's a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77952090/how-do-you-catch-exceptions-in-project-reactor/77952277)*

I try to get the hang of Project Reactor. As part of it, I learn to catch errors that Project Reactor swallows and (almost) never rethrows outside. Here was my attempt at it

```java
@Test
void test() {
    WebClient.builder().build()
        .get()
        .uri("https://httpbin.org/status/404")
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(String.class)
        .subscribe(
                s -> System.out.println("Success: " + s),
                t -> System.out.println("Failure: " + t.getMessage())
        );
}
```

To my surprise, nothing happened: no logs, no nothing. After a while I discovered that putting an extra `sleep()` call makes the difference

```java
@Test
void test() {
        // ...
        Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

I have only one explanation: the code was executed in some daemon thread so the JVM didn't initially wait for it to complete. I never saw any mention of it in the [official guide](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#error.handling) (it is a possibility I missed something)

What is the correct explanation for this behavior?

**UPD**

This might be of relevance. From the method's [Javadoc](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#subscribe-java.util.function.Consumer-java.util.function.Consumer-)

> Keep in mind that since the sequence can be asynchronous, this will immediately return control to the calling thread. This can give the impression the consumer is not invoked when executing in a main thread or a unit test for instance.

However, I didn't find anything in documentation that specifically addressed default schedulers/threads

I also tried to run it with the debugger, but I never spotted any mention of any concurrent classes (and the source code appeared rather confusing to me)

Comment: It's not about errors, it's just how `subscribe` work. For a test you may use `.block` instead, which waits for execution. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59607165/what-is-the-difference-between-block-subscribe-and-subscribe

Comment: @IgorArtamonov thank you for the reference! However, chaining `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newParallel("my-scheduler", 5, false))` didn't change anything. It's almost as if reactor gives preference to its own daemon scheduler regardless

Comment: I mean you're mixing two different things and that's what confuses you. `onError*()` works as they should, but you cannot see it with `.subscribe()` because it runs everything in different thread. To test it in the same thread you need to `.block()`. A _sleep_ is a trick that may show you what happens in other threads by giving some time, but it's not a reliable way to test

Comment: @IgorArtamonov Isn't that `subscribeOn` call telling Reactor to execute subscriber callbacks on non-daemons? Why doesn't it listen?

Comment: when you "are reactive", know the docs, and (still) "fight" .... why not progress to ["test chapter"](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#testing)!? ;*) (...-> StepVerifier!?;)

Comment: @xerx593 I know `StepVerifier`. It's not a question about testing, though. I want to know what threads are used to execute subscriber callbacks and how I can influence it (specifically make it use regular, non-daemon threads)

Comment: @xerx593 this question's purpose is, broadly, to help me get to know Reactor better and learn to configure it. Not help me with testing

Comment: @JoreJoh well, in general, you cannot control the threads. You can specify where the initial subscription starts, but the upstream subscribers can change it. And most importantly, it's just a subscription, and the actual execution thread is more likely to be controlled by a publisher.

Comment: @IgorArtamonov what is that `subscribeOn()` all about then if I can't pass my own non-daemon scheduler anyway, even in my minimalistic example without a lot of operators?

Comment: That's only for the subscriber, but it's executed in a publisher thread. Which may, or may not, reuse the same thread. It depends on a particular publisher. It's designed do other things, not to pass a thread to execute something.

Comment: @IgorArtamonov don't those consumers constitute subscriber code?

Comment: No, it's just consumers. A _subscriber_ notifies what it needs, like _"give me 10 items"_, which executed in the subscriber thread and sent to the publisher. Then this thread may complete. And it's job of a publisher to sent those 10 items. If it's immediately available (i.e., it's not a IO) then it can send in the same thread, b/c no reason to spin a new one. For something that waits for a result (ex. IO), it does that in a new thread, and [usually] uses it to send those 10 items back. That's where all the operations happen. Usually. But not always, expect switching a thread at any step.

Comment: If you want to set a thread for the `.subscribe()` consumer, you may use `.publishOn` immediately before it. Then the publisher switch the thread to the specified one and use that thread to push data to the consumer.